# Angular-google-maps Transparent white square on marker

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps

I need your help on some bug that i have encountered, with no solutions on documentation, hope someone solved it !

I have GoogleMaps who works with angular-google-maps, one is fully functionnal with markers / polylines and windows.

But i have one map that only contain one marker with transparent white square around, how to get rid of this square please ?

Here is the code in my HTML :

```
<div class="map" id="map">
      <ui-gmap-google-map center='activity.map.center' zoom='activity.map.zoom'>

        <ui-gmap-marker idKey="activity.map.marker.id" coords="activity.map.marker.coords">
        </ui-gmap-marker>
      </ui-gmap-google-map>
 </div>
```

And here is my map declaration :

```
vm.map = {
  center: {
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0
  },
  zoom: 5,
  marker: {
    id: 0,
    coords: {
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null
    }
  }
};
vm.map.marker.coords.latitude = vm.activity.latitudePrevue;
vm.map.marker.coords.longitude = vm.activity.longitudePrevue;
```

And here is the map with the transparent square : [Transparent square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYou8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Closed : It was a CSS problem from the parent div classes

```
<div class="...">
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
</div>
```